# How to remove a property from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with `name` and `age` property:

```js
[
  { name: "Matthew", age: 23 },
  { name: "James", age: 20 }, 
  { name: "Daniel", age: 25 },
  { name: "Joshua", age: 22 }
]
```

I want to remove `age` property from all of the objects and print in console like

```js
[
  { name: "Matthew" },
  { name: "James" }, 
  { name: "Daniel" },
  { name: "Joshua" }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over your array and use `delete` keyword.

```js
let array = [
  { name: "Matthew", age: 23 },
  { name: "James", age: 20 }, 
  { name: "Daniel", age: 25 },
  { name: "Joshua", age: 22 }
]
array.forEach(function(v){ delete v.age });
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function to achieve this.

`let output = test.map(({name}) => ({name}));`

If you want to filter with multiple object you can add after `name` like `{name, salary}`

```js
var test =[
  { name: "Matthew", age: 23 },
  { name: "James", age: 20 }, 
  { name: "Daniel", age: 25 },
  { name: "Joshua", age: 22 }
];
let output = test.map(({name}) => ({name}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const newData = oldData.map(item=>({name:item.name}))
```

Comment: this way we have the problem that if the array object has other keys and the developer don't want to remove others, but only "age" property. Your solution will fail.